# installing mysql5.6.12 in ubuntu 12.10 error:/etc/mysql/conf.d is missing

Tags: ubuntu-12.10, conf.d, mysql-5.6

I am trying to install mysql in ubuntu 12.10. Downloaded 'MySQL-5.6.12-1.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm-bundle' from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/. Extracted it and tried to install using "rpm -i MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.linux_glibc2.5.i386". Since it was not possible, used "sudo alien -i MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.linux_glibc2.5.i386". Did the same for all the other files inside the directory MySQL-5.6.12-1.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm-bundle. Then tried 'mysql' command in terminal, but it showed error

"mysql: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted"

checked /etc/mysql directory. The only file present inside was my.cnf
content:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:

# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/se...variables.html


# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram


# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice = 0


[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover = BACKUP
#max_connections = 100
#table_cache = 64
#thread_concurrency = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
# other settings you may need to change.
#server-id = 1
#log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = 100M
#binlog_do_db = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem





[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 16M


[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition


[isamchk]
key_buffer = 16M


#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
# The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Don't know how to fix this error.
I am trying to learn mysql and installing it for the first time.
Don't know whether this forum is appropriate for this problem.
Kindly help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: try sudo install mysql this should automatically install mysql

Comment: @Satya It is not working.

Comment: what is the error you are getting @user2508575

Comment: @Satya actually you were right. It is there in repo. I didn't specify like mysql-server.

Comment: anyway it got solved.  http://serverfault.com/questions/520751/installing-mysql5-6-12-in-ubuntu-12-10-error-etc-mysql-conf-d-is-missing                          Thanks for your help